# trigger click with interval

Tags: jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I have JS as

```
setTimeout(function() {
setInterval(function() {
    $('.home-tab-news').trigger('click');
}, 15000);
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function() {
setInterval(function() {
    $('.home-tab-project').trigger('click');
}, 15000);
}, 10000);

setTimeout(function() {
setInterval(function() {
    $('.home-tab-piechart').trigger('click');
}, 15000);
}, 15000);
```

What I want it to do is trigger each every 10 seconds in a loop (it does this at the moment, but the timings on the first are off?)

Also how do I stop the transitions if someone clicks on a tab - at the moment, if someone clicks a tab themselves the transitions keep happening.

Comment: To stop it, set a variable to the result of `setInterval`, and then call `clearInterval(thatVariable)`.

Comment: if you want them to run every 10 seconds, the argument to `setInterval` should be `10000`. `15000` is every 15 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the `15000` in the first one? it means 15,000 milliseconds. for 10 seconds you need to put 10,000.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.home-tab-news').trigger('click');
    }, 10000);
}, 10000);
```

as for stopping it, you simply assign the interval to a var:

```
var interval1;

setTimeout(function() {
    interval1 = setInterval(function() {
        $('.home-tab-news').trigger('click');
    }, 10000);
}, 10000);
```

and after tab click:

```
clearInterval(interval1);
```

### UPDATE:

in order to clear the interval when the user clicks a tab, you attach a click handler yo all your tabs, and clear the interval when the handler fires. since you trigger the click programatically too, you need to differentiate between the programatical click and manual click, i would to it with a flag;

about the timing, i would suggest using a variable to indicate current tab, and cycle through them while shifting the variable.

```
var is_manual = true;
var interval1;
var Current_Tab = 1;
var Cycle_Speed_Seconds = 1;
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("start");
        //set a click handler to your tabs:
        $('.home-tab-news, .home-tab-project, .home-tab-piechart').click(function () {
            console.log("click");
            //check if clicked manually or automatically:
            if (is_manual == false) {
                //if automatic, clear flag and continue
                is_manual = true;
            } else if (is_manual == true) {
                //if manual, clear interval
                clearInterval(interval1);
            }

            //execute default action:
            return true;
        });
        //set the interval to swap between tabs
        interval1 = setInterval(function () {
            //indicate that the click was trigerred automatically:
            is_manual = false;
            if (Current_Tab == 1) {
                Current_Tab = 2;
                $('.home-tab-news').trigger('click');
            } else if (Current_Tab == 2) {
                Current_Tab = 3;
                $('.home-tab-project').trigger('click');
            } else if (Current_Tab == 3) {
                Current_Tab = 1;
                $('.home-tab-piechart').trigger('click');
            }

        },Cycle_Speed_Seconds* 1000);
    }, 0);
});
```

a bit long, but i believe you understand my point. if you have any questions feel free to ask

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/gb4663t6/)**</kbd>

Comment: Sorry - where do I place the clearInterval(interval1); within that code? Also, the tabs are not transitioning every 10 secs. With the original code it takes about 15 secs to start and then they transition every 5 secs... I want each one appearing one after the other every 10 seconds...

Comment: the `clearInterval` you put when you want to clear it, as i understood from your question you want to stop the transitions when the user clicks a tab manually, so you need to attach a click handler to the tabs (or alter an existing one) and there you clear the interval. regarding the timing, you want them all cycle in a 10 second cycles? if yes, i will update my answer with an example

Comment: I get a typeError undefined on the function (am running through Wordpress). Secondly was does this line do $("#tabs").tabs(); -> I change the #tabs to my ul class (home-tabs) but what relates back to tabs()?

Comment: Oh dont mind this line, its just how i created the tabs for the example, its a jquey UI tabs. You need to just set the ingerval on your own tabs. Also, can you isolate the line that gives you the error? Which type it says is undefined? Have you included my custom variables?

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax**

setInterval(function,milliseconds,lang)

**Parameter Values**

```
Parameter         Description

function         Required. The function that will be executed 
milliseconds     Required. The intervals (in milliseconds) on how often to execute the code 
lang             Optional. JScript | VBScript | JavaScript
```

**Return Value**

An integer with the ID value of the timer that is set. Use this value with the clearInterval() method to cancel the timer.

**Example** :-

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()}, 10000); //// For 10 seconds its 10 * 1000

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```